# facing error when trying to read using flat file source In SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, flat-file

I am trying to read a comma separated text file using flat file source in ssis package. text file only has one column values. when i select unicode codepage for this it is throwing an error:

`The specified header or data row delimiter "Comma{,}" is not found after scanning 655536 bytes of the file`

Sample File:-

```
Styleid,
123456,
123456,
123456,
```

Can any anyone please tell me how to resolve this.

Comment: Is it unicode data? Is your flat file connection manager specified as Fixed Width, ragged right, etc?

Comment: @@Billinkc Yes the data is unicode but i am not specifying connection manager as fixed width. also if i specify code page other than Unicode it is populating the data, but throwing other errors

Answer (score 0):

Appears that instead of rows you have one long string. Try setting your row delimiter to Comma.

[image]